# WCF and AFNetworking Uploading

Tags: wcf, afnetworking

Having a great time figuring this out, Google led me in directions not worthing taking.

I am looking to use AFNetworking to stream multiple files to a WCF service and using the query string parameters to send up ids and such.

I would post the code that I have but at the moment it's not worth it.

I think the issue is with the WCF end of things as I cannot figure out how to wire it up correctly.

If anyone can provide some solid direction on this I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just handled the iOS side of an AFNetworking/WCF issue so I can only offer some help from that perspective. The reason we had issues was because of the 65k upload limit on WCF side (http://forums.asp.net/t/1715789.aspx/1?64kb+limit+on+upload+of+file). Once our server guy upped the upload limit our code worked like a charm.